# ToDo list using classes

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone I'm struggling with toDo list using classes in javascript. It's my first code using OOP and I don't know how to connect everything to obtain the best result. I have a problem with how to pass input to **toDo array** and set it in **ul mark**.
My code consist of two classes:

1. List, where I add and remove elements from array and,
2. Render where I would like to display element's added or removed.

Can anyone help me?

```js
class List {
  #toDo = [];
  constructor(render) {
    this.render = render;
    this.render.renderList(this.toDo);
  }

  addTask(list) {
    this.toDo.push(list);
    this.render.renderList(this.toDo.push(list));
  }

  removeTask(list) {
    this.toDo.filter((word) => word != list);
  }
}

class Render {
  constructor(input) {
    this.input = input;
    const task = this.input.querySelector("input");
    const btn = this.input.querySelector("button");
    const ul = this.input.querySelector(".tasks");
  }
  onRemoveTaskCallBack = () => {};
  renderList(task) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = task + "<button>Delete</button>";
  }
}

const render = new Render(document.querySelector("#to-do-container"));
const list = new List(render);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      div {
        margin: 80px auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      input {
        width: 20%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="to-do-container">
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Add Task</button>
      <ul class="tasks"></ul>
    </div>

    <script src="List.js"></script>
    <script src="Render.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class List {
  toDo = [];
  constructor(render) {
    this.render = render;
    this.render.renderList(this.toDo);
  }

  addTask(task) {
    this.toDo.push(task);
    this.render.renderList(this.toDo);
  }

  removeTask(task) {
    this.toDo = this.toDo.filter((word) => word !== task);
    this.render.renderList(this.toDo);
  }
}

class Render {
  constructor(input) {
    this.input = input;
    const taskInput = this.input.querySelector("input");
    const addButton = this.input.querySelector("button");
    const ul = this.input.querySelector(".tasks");

    addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const task = taskInput.value.trim();
      if (task !== "") {
        list.addTask(task);
        taskInput.value = "";
      }
    });

    ul.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
        const task = event.target.previousSibling.textContent;
        list.removeTask(task);
      }
    });
  }

  renderList(toDo) {
    const ul = this.input.querySelector(".tasks");
    ul.innerHTML = "";
    toDo.forEach((task) => {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      li.textContent = task;
      const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
      deleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
      li.appendChild(deleteButton);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
  }
}

const render = new Render(document.querySelector("#to-do-container"));
const list = new List(render);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      div {
        margin: 80px auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
      input {
        width: 20%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="to-do-container">
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Add Task</button>
      <ul class="tasks"></ul>
    </div>

    <script src="List.js"></script>
    <script src="Render.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to ask about:
  const task = event.target.previousSibling.textContent; Why you used textContent? PreviousSibling without textContent also return text.

Comment: Using textContent ensures that we only get the text content of the previous sibling element without any extra whitespace or line breaks. Therefore, it is a more reliable way to retrieve the text value of the element.